# Как подписать обновление приложения сертификатом?

Tags: android, google-play

Я хочу выпустить обновление приложения в play market, но у меня ошибка:

```
Сбой при загрузке
Добавленные ранее APK-файлы подписаны сертификатами с цифровыми отпечатками
[ SHA1: ... ]
, а новый APK-файл – сертификатом с отпечатком
[ SHA1: ... ]
. Используйте один и тот же сертификат.
```

Как подписать обновленное приложение нужным сертификатом?

Comment: Нужно использовать для подписи те же сертификаты, что и для предидущей версии.

Comment: eugeneek, это понятно, но не понятно как именно это сделать

Comment: http://java-help.ru/android-studio-create-signed-apk/ - только вместо генерации ключей выберите ваши существующие

Comment: просто в студии надимаешь generate signed apk и этот апк загружаешь в консоли